# k8s partial default recovery via yaml repo?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes and wondering if there is universal repo where I can fetch and apply default yaml configurations in case I accidentally delete them  , for example if I accidentally delete any default resource like apiservice networking or other ... , could I restore it with simply by:

```
 kubectl apply -f <k8s-resource-repo-uri>
```

And if there is such a repo how to identify the necessary yaml for the relevant kubernetes resource version ?

P.S.
I know that I can backup the whole ETCD and restore in case of issues , but I am wondering if there is universal yaml repo location where I can restore partially specific default resources?
For example all the resources I get with:

```
 kubectl get apiservices
```

or

```
 kubectl api-resources
```

I can delete them , but can I restore easily from some universal place?

For example I can do:

```
kubectl delete apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io v1.networking.k8s.io
```

But dont know how to recover after , any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the critical `kube-system` pods tend to be "static pods".
This means that they get restored automatically if you happen to just `kubectl delete` them.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/

For most other resources, e.g. your workload, it's good practice to have your own git repo with all the yaml files, so that you can redeploy it in case it's ever lost.

Comment: I know about the static pods located here: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/ , but actually they cannot be deleted since they are automatically recreated from the mafiest files in the master nodes ... , but I am asking about general resources and how they can be re-created , I guess those are installed on cluster init , but I guess there  is easy way to restore them from k8s repos that I am searching for ...